# Access the new document object after redirection to a new page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm writing a Greasemonkey userscript to loop through several webpages, harvesting some html from each one.

However, after I've moved to the second in the series of pages, the document object still refers to the first page, even if I wait until the second page has completely loaded. How can I update or refresh the document object so that it refers to the new page?

Here's my complete script in which the document object always refers to the first page:

```
(function($) {

//create a button       
myButton = document.createElement("input");
myButton.type = "button";
myButton.value = "Click here";
myButton.id = "display";
placeHolder = document.getElementById("someId");
placeHolder.parentNode.insertBefore(myButton, placeHolder.nextSibling);

//function to be called when button is clicked
$("#display").click(function(){

   //harvest some html on page 1 and save it
   my_list = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0];
   my_list_html=my_list.innerHTML;
   localStorage.setItem('page1', my_list_html);

   //find a certain URL on page 1
   var nextPageLink = $(".myClass2").first().find("a");

   //go to page 2
   actuateLink(nextPageLink[0]);

   //once page 2 has loaded, harvest some html on page 2
   (function poll(){
       if(document.readyState === "complete")
       {

          my_list2 = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0]; //this should be the document object of page 2, but in fact it's still the document object of page 1
          my_list_html2=my_list2.innerHTML;
          console.log('Content from page 1:',localStorage.getItem('page1')); // this prints the html harvested from page 1
          console.log('Content from page 2:',my_list_html2); // this also prints the html harvested from page 1

       }
       else
       {    
          setTimeout(poll,500);
       }    
   })();

});

//function for following a link
function actuateLink(link)
{
   window.location.href = link.href;
}

})(jQuery);
```

(I'm harvesting the html from different pages in order to then combine it together and display it all in one page. Edited to clarify that I'm running the script with the Greasemonkey extension for firefox.)

Comment: Are you *currently* running this with Greasemonkey/as a user script, or just in a page normally? If the latter, it's not going to work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I'm currently running this with Greasemonkey.

Comment: Doesn't your user script start over (in some sense) when a new page is loaded?